# Searchkick combine a random query with boost_by_recency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying to create a query where I could retrieve a collection of random items but give a little boost in this randomization for the newly created items.

Currently, I'm able to do the two different queries separately but can't do it in just one. I'm a bit confused with the syntax and I guess this must be possible to achieve this.

Here is what I do to get a random collection:

```
Item.search( "*", body: {query: {function_score: {random_score: {seed: Time.zone.now.to_i}}} })
```

And here is what I do to boost the newly created items in a search (using the `boost_by_recency` option):

```
Item.search( "*", boost_by_recency: {created_at: {scale: "7d", decay: 0.5}})
```

When I try to merge the two queries I get errors messages about the syntax:

```
Item.search( "*", boost_by_recency: {created_at: {scale: "7d", decay: 0.5}}, body: {query: {function_score: {random_score: {seed: Time.zone.now.to_i}}} })
```

Gives me : `ArgumentError (Options incompatible with body option: boost_by_recency)`